# Visual Studio 15 не применяются изменения в коде

Tags: c++, visual-studio

До этого пользовался VS10 и вместе с переходом на Win10 решил попробовать VS15.
В общем, дело такое...
Пишу код, запускаю Debug(F5), окей, всё норм.
Снова пишу код, ввожу всякие изменения, жму F5, открывается всё тоже самое, что было до первого запуска Debug'а. То есть, он не скомпилировал ничерта.
Вот сейчас потыкал, получается надо сначала выполнять "Build"/"Rebuild", а потом уже запускать Debug. Это не удобно, как заставить его сразу применять изменения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tools - Options - Projects and Solutions - Build and Run

[image: Build and Run]

И, на будущее, поосторожнее с флажком в этом диалоге

[image: Run last successful version]

Comment: В качестве офтопа и для справки. В Виндоуз, сочетание Alt+PrintScreen создает снимок активного окна, а не всего экрана. Это дает возможность не париться с вырезанием окон.

Comment: @Cerbo, это кому комментарий?

Comment: Коментарий для вас @Qweriy

Comment: @Cerbo, я вообще-то знаю, а почему ты решил, что это не так? Скорее всего так их и делал. Ну или Snap'ом.

Comment: По уголкам окон

Comment: @Cerbo, это тень окна. Специально проверил. Alt+PrintScreen и вставка в Paint оставляет именно такие уголки. Win7.